How can I change default file picker?
I want to change my default file picker, but when I go to settings, the option to change the default file picker doesn’t appear. I’d like to know if there are any apps or modules (I have root access) that could help me make this change. I also have Termux, so if anyone has code that could help, I'd appreciate it. Currently, my default file picker is com.android.documentsui, and I want to change it to com.marc.files.
